# How to track async threads and handle broken pipe errors with SSE emitter?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, tomcat

I'm looking to catch `IOException`s caused by a broken pipe before the async threads dispatch the result to Tomcat. Essentially the client disconnects and the error bubbles up to Tomcat before I can catch the issue. I have no control over the client(s).

I have a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` in my Controller and my endpoint looks like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/mySSEStream")
    public SseEmitter sseEmitter() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
        MyRunner streamingRunner = new MyRunner(emitter);
        cachedThreadPool.execute(streamingRunner);
        return emitter;
    }
```

MyRunner:

```
public class MyRunner implements Runnable {
    private final SseEmitter sseEmitter;

    public StreamingRunner(SseEmitter sseEmitter) {
        this.sseEmitter = sseEmitter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sendData();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            sseEmitter.completeWithError(ioException);
        } finally {
            try {
                sseEmitter.complete();
            } catch (IllegalStateException illegalStateException) {
                log.debug("SSE Emitter already closed...");
            }
        }
    }
```

So the controller thread creates the SSE emitter, a second thread (named `http-nio-9998-exec-1`) accepts the request, returns a 200, and begins emitting data. Then I get a debug log saying that the Dispatcher Servlet is "Exiting but response remains open for further handling". The client disconnect happens. Then the third thread (named `http-nio-9998-exec-2`) begins processing the broken pipe error. I get a message `WebAsyncManager - Async error, dispatch to /mySSEStream`. However, no matter how I try to catch the error, it bubbles up to Tomcat and responds with a 500 error. I see this in the debugger. Obviously the 500 doesn't arrive at the client, but our endpoint metrics are littered with 500 errors.

I can't catch this error anywhere. I've tried using the `AsyncHandlerInterceptor` to no avail. That recommends using the `WebAsyncManager` to register a deferred result, but I couldn't get that working. I've tried @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler, but that thread talks directly to the Tomcat container. I've also tried Filter but that doesn't work for outbound messages, it only filters incoming from Tomcat.

I'm sure I'm missing something here and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.